# Can i use @using(null) to isolate the variables in the View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

In some cases, I use the same variable names in the one View, for this i use @using statement with null, like this:

```
<div>
    @using (null) {
        var url = "http://example.com/";
        <a href="@url">example.com</a>
    }

    @using (null) {
        var url = "http://simple.com";
        <a href="@url">simple.com</a>
    }
</div>
```

Wanted to clarify whether I'm doing well?

Comment: Why do you want to use a variable at all like this?

Comment: There are small blocks of code in the View for which I do not want to come up with unique names for variables.

Comment: I mean (in a roundabout way) why are you not doing all this in your controller? Code should be a last resort in your view.

Comment: doesn't `@{ /*...*/ }` do that much more succinctly?

Comment: If you have several blocks of similar repeated content in your view, a partial view might be a better solution.  You can pass the string as the model and solve your variable problem at the same time

Comment: `@{/*...*/}` No isolates variables.

Comment: I really think you're missing the point of MVC by doing things like that.

Comment: I appreciate you may have a reason for doing this. But, this is bad, bad, bad. No good can come of what you intend to do here/ I strongly suggest that you do logic that at the controller level, and use a viewmodel with a `Url` parameter to render the url. Don't do logic like this in the view. Certainly, if I saw code like that, I'd start crying :)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Knew what I was doing something wrong.